# what does .dtype do?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python, and don't understand what `.dtype` does. 
For example:

```
>>> aa
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
>>> aa.dtype = "float64"
>>> aa
array([  4.24399158e-314,   8.48798317e-314,   1.27319747e-313,
     1.69759663e-313])
```

I thought dtype is a property of aa, which should be int, and if I assign `aa.dtype = "float64"` 
 then`aa` should become `array([1.0 ,2.0 ,3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0])`.

Why does it changes its value and size? 
What does it mean?

I was actually learning from a piece of code, and shall I paste it here:

```
def to_1d(array):
 """prepares an array into a 1d real vector"""
    a = array.copy() # copy the array, to avoid changing global
    orig_dtype = a.dtype
    a.dtype = "float64" # this doubles the size of array
    orig_shape = a.shape
    return a.ravel(), (orig_dtype, orig_shape) #flatten and return
```

I think it shouldn't change the value of the input array but only change its size. Confused of how the function works

Comment: When in doubt, [read the manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes)

Comment: i have tried to understand the manual, however, its english and computing language is so hard for me, couldnt grapse infomations i need.

Comment: @user1233157: it is not the most elegantly written prose, is it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First off, the code you're learning from is flawed. It almost certainly doesn't do what the original author thought it did based on the comments in the code.

What the author probably meant was this:

```
def to_1d(array):
    """prepares an array into a 1d real vector"""
    return array.astype(np.float64).ravel()
```

However, if `array` is always going to be an array of complex numbers, then the original code makes some sense.

The only cases where viewing the array (`a.dtype = 'float64'` is equivalent to doing `a = a.view('float64')`) would double its size is if it's a complex array (`numpy.complex128`) or a 128-bit floating point array.  For any other dtype, it doesn't make much sense.

For the specific case of a *complex* array, the original code would convert something like `np.array([0.5+1j, 9.0+1.33j])` into `np.array([0.5, 1.0, 9.0, 1.33])`.

A cleaner way to write that would be:

```
def complex_to_iterleaved_real(array):
     """prepares a complex array into an "interleaved" 1d real vector"""
    return array.copy().view('float64').ravel()
```

(I'm ignoring the part about returning the original dtype and shape, for the moment.)

---

## Background on numpy arrays

To explain what's going on here, you need to understand a bit about what numpy arrays are.

A numpy array consists of a "raw" memory buffer that is interpreted as an array through "views".  You can think of all numpy arrays as views.

Views, in the numpy sense, are just a different way of slicing and dicing the same memory buffer without making a copy.

A view has a shape, a data type (dtype), an offset, and strides.  Where possible, indexing/reshaping operations on a numpy array will just return a view of the original memory buffer.

This means that things like `y = x.T` or `y = x[::2]` don't use any extra memory, and don't make copies of `x`.

So, if we have an array similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

We could reshape it by doing either:

```
x = x.reshape((2, 5))
```

or

```
x.shape = (2, 5)
```

For readability, the first option is better. They're (almost) exactly equivalent, though. Neither one will make a copy that will use up more memory (the first will result in a new python object, but that's beside the point, at the moment.).

---

## Dtypes and views

The same thing applies to the dtype.  We can view an array as a different dtype by either setting `x.dtype` or by calling `x.view(...)`.

So we can do things like this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int)

print 'The original array'
print x

print '\n...Viewed as unsigned 8-bit integers (notice the length change!)'
y = x.view(np.uint8)
print y

print '\n...Doing the same thing by setting the dtype'
x.dtype = np.uint8
print x

print '\n...And we can set the dtype again and go back to the original.'
x.dtype = np.int
print x
```

Which yields:

```
The original array
[1 2 3]

...Viewed as unsigned 8-bit integers (notice the length change!)
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

...Doing the same thing by setting the dtype
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

...And we can set the dtype again and go back to the original.
[1 2 3]
```

Keep in mind, though, that this is giving you low-level control over the way that the memory buffer is interpreted.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10, dtype=np.int)

print 'An integer array:', x
print 'But if we view it as a float:', x.view(np.float)
print "...It's probably not what we expected..."
```

This yields:

```
An integer array: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
But if we view it as a float: [  0.00000000e+000   4.94065646e-324   
   9.88131292e-324   1.48219694e-323   1.97626258e-323   
   2.47032823e-323   2.96439388e-323   3.45845952e-323
   3.95252517e-323   4.44659081e-323]
...It's probably not what we expected...
```

So, we're interpreting the underlying bits of the original memory buffer as floats, in this case.

**If we wanted to make a new copy with the ints recasted as floats, we'd use x.astype(np.float).**

---

## Complex Numbers

Complex numbers are stored (in both C, python, and numpy) as two floats. The first is the real part and the second is the imaginary part.

So, if we do:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.5+1j, 1.0+2j, 3.0+0j])
```

We can see the real (`x.real`) and imaginary (`x.imag`) parts.  If we convert this to a float, we'll get a warning about discarding the imaginary part, and we'll get an array with just the real part.

```
print x.real
print x.astype(float)
```

`astype` makes a copy and converts the values to the new type.

However, if we view this array as a float, we'll get a sequence of `item1.real, item1.imag, item2.real, item2.imag, ...`.

```
print x
print x.view(float)
```

yields:

```
[ 0.5+1.j  1.0+2.j  3.0+0.j]
[ 0.5  1.   1.   2.   3.   0. ]
```

Each complex number is essentially two floats, so if we change how numpy interprets the underlying memory buffer, we get an array of twice the length.

Hopefully that helps clear things up a bit...

Comment: omg, i have spent hours on his code. gosh! thanks for pointing out, may i ask, apart from the dtype part, the rest of his code is still right? i mean the reshape parts, thanks.

Comment: Well, if you want to return a _copy_ of the array as a 1D vector, just call `array.flatten()`.  However, see my updated answer... If `array` was _always_ going to be a complex array, then the code does make some sense, but it's misleadingly documented, anyway.

Comment: thank you so much! the input array is indeed a complex array, now i understood! haha,happy

Comment: @Joe Do you have a good recommendation on documentation for Numpy. For example, this is as much use as a snowball in hell: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dtype.html#numpy.ndarray.dtype  Presumably there is good documentation somewhere. I personally would find it very useful.  +1

Comment: @JoeKington , again, thank you so much for your extra infomation, i have learnt a lot from what you wrote, very comperhensive, i am very appreciated!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The "see also" links are key.  If you'll notice, the "see also" bit points you to the documentation for `numpy.dtype`. What you linked to just points out (as it should, i.m.o.) that `ndarray.dtype` is an instance of `numpy.dtype` and points you to the full documentation with "see also".  For more general concepts about what `ndarray`s are, the main entry point for the documentation gives an extensive discussion: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.html

Comment: So I followed the See Also and that's not really any use. That just tells me about the class `numpy.dtype`. What's utterly missing from the doc I linked to is what happens when you assign to `ndarray.dtype`. This answer is the best description that I have found yet!

Answer (score 6):

By changing the dtype in this way, you are changing the way a fixed block of memory is being interpreted.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],dtype='int8')
>>> a
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int8)
>>> a.dtype='int64'
>>> a
array([1])
```

Note how the change from `int8` to `int64` changed an 8 element, 8 bit integer array, into a 1 element, 64 bit array. It is the same 8 byte block however. On my i7 machine with native endianess, the byte pattern is the same as `1` in an int64 format.

Change the position of the 1:

```
>>> a=np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],dtype='int8')
>>> a.dtype='int64'
>>> a
array([16777216])
```

Another example:

```
>>> a=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],dtype='int32')
>>> a.dtype='int64'
>>> a
array([0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Change the position of the `1` in the 32 byte, 32 bit array:

```
>>> a=np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],dtype='int32')
>>> a.dtype='int64'
>>> a
array([         0, 4294967296,          0,          0])
```

It is the same block of bits reinterpreted.

Comment: although i have given the tick to Joe, and ur answer is great, very good examples! thank you.

Comment: @user1233157: His answered deserved it! You could still give me a vote tho   :-)

Comment: Nice answer, by the way! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

After messing around with it, I think manually assigning dtype does a reinterpret cast rather than what you want. Meaning I think it interprets the data directly as a float rather than converting it to one. Maybe you could try `aa = numpy.array(aa.map(float, aa))`.

Further Explanation: dtype is the type of the data. To quote verbatim from the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

> A data type object (an instance of numpy.dtype class) describes how
>   the bytes in the fixed-size block of memory corresponding to an array
>   item should be interpreted.

ints and floats don't have the same bit patterns, meaning you can't just look at the memory for an int and it would be the same number when you look at it as a float. By setting dtype to float64 you are just telling the computer to read that memory as float64 instead of actually converting the integer numbers to floating point numbers.

Comment: thank you very much fro replying, and i am actually learning from a picec of code, which should does the job of converting an array into a 1 dimensional vector, i m just confused of why it changed the value.

Comment: i have updated my question, pasted the code i was refering to. thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.dtype.html#numpy.ndarray.dtype) for the `dtype` attribute of `ndarray` is not very useful at all. Looking at your output it would seem that the buffer of eight 4 byte integers is being reinterpreted as four 8 byte floats.

But what you want is to specify the `dtype` in the array creation:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype="float64")
```

Comment: The documentation for `dtype` is here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes for what it's worth. What you linked to isn't even the documentation dtype class (which is here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype), it's just the documentation for `ndarray.dtype`, which points you to the other documentation.

Comment: i have updated my question, would you please have a look? thanks alot:)

Comment: Well, I answered the original question, and you have accepted a very comprehensive answer that covers all the bases. I think our work here is done!